# Parallel runs in N-process batches in BASH

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, wait, sleep

I have a for loop and I want to process it 4 times in parallel at a time.
I tried the following code from the page https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop:

```
task(){
sleep 0.5; echo "$1";
}
N=4
(
for thing in a b c d e f g; do
   ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
   task "$thing" &
done
)
```

I have stored the above file as test.sh, the output I get it is as follows:

```
path$ ./test.sh
a
b
c
d
path$ e
f
g
```

and the cursor doesn't come back to my terminal after 'g', it waits/ sleeps indefinitely.I want the cursor come back to my terminal and also I don't understand why the output 'e' has my path preceding it, shouldn't the output be displayed as 'a' to 'g' continuously and the code should stop?

Comment: Your code will do the 7 things in the loop just once, because that loop is not inside another loop. Yet you say you want to process the loop 4 times? So, are there really 28 things to process?

Comment: What should be the overall order? a, b, c & d all run in parallel till all have finished, then e, f, g & a all run in parallel till they all finish maybe?

Comment: yes @MarkSetchell I want to do a, b, c & d all run in parallel till all have finished, then e, f, g & a all run in parallel till they all finish

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty hard to understand what you want, but I think you want to do 7 things, called `a`,`b`,`c`...`g` in parallel, no more than 4 instances at a time.

If so, you could try this:

```
echo {a..g} | xargs -P4 -n1 bash -c 'echo "$1"; sleep 2' {}
```

That sends the letters `a`..`g` into `xargs` which then starts a new `bash` shell for each letter, passing one letter (`-n1`) to the shell as `{}`. The `bash` shell picks up the parameter (its first parameter being `$1`) and echoes it then waits 2 seconds before exiting - so you can see the pause.

The `-P4` tells `xargs` to run 4 instances of `bash` at a time in parallel.

Here is a little video of it running. The first one uses `-P4` and runs in groups of 4, the second sequence uses `-P2` and does 2 at a time:

[image]

---

Or, more simply, if you don't mind spending 10 seconds installing **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel -j4 -k  'echo {}; sleep 2' ::: {a..g}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I would really like if you could edit my code given above instead of giving a command line solution since a command line solution is possible in this case but in reality my task () function is going to have many more things to process than just echoing the variable

Comment: Just do `export -f task` to export your `task()`, then do `parallel ... task`

Answer (score 0):

If you press enter toy can see than you are in normal shell. If you want to wait batched process before exit the script just add `wait` at the end of script

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand why do I need to press enter to return to the normal shell instead of it returning by itself on completion of the code. Also, could you elaborate on "If you want to wait batched process before exit the script just add wait at the end of script"

Comment: You see prompt `path$` - that mean than you script is ended. And you are in shell. `wait` is a bash command than wait all runned in current shell background process.

Comment: so when i see the line 'path$ e' the code has ended but its just printing stuff with a delay?